# 画像を小さく表示したい

Tags: サポート, markdown

質問にスクリーンショットなどの画像を入れたいのですが、そのままだと必要以上に大きく表示されてしまいます。小さくするには手動で縮小したものをアップロードするしか無いのでしょうか？

[image: タージ・マハルの写真です]

<sup>画像: CC BY-SA, uploaded by [Jbarta](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Jbarta), originally taken by [Yann](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Yann), downloaded from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Taj_Mahal,_Agra,_India_edit3.jpg)</sup>

Answer (score 8):

元々の画像 `https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmjId.jpg` だけのまま、小さく表示する方法があります。

### 方法1: img タグを使う

スタック・オーバーフローでは HTML の img タグが有効です。したがって `width` や `height` を使って `<img src="画像URL" width="幅">` のように書くことで縮小できます。

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmjId.jpg" width="128">
```

[image]

元画像へのリンクも含めるためには、Markdown か HTML でハイパーリンクすると良いです。

```markdown
[<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmjId.jpg" width="128">][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmjId.jpg
```

または

```html
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmjId.jpg"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmjId.jpg" width="128"></a>
```

[image]

### 方法2: Imgur の API を使う

スタック・オーバーフローが画像の保存先として使っている Imgur は、URL 末尾の `.jpg` の前に適切なアルファベット 1 文字を入れると自動的にリサイズしてくれます。たとえば `wmjId.jpg` に `s` を追加して `wmjIds.jpg` とすると小さい正方形にリサイズされます。クリックしたときのリンク先は元の大きさにしたいので、元の URL を残しつつ次のように書くと良さげです。

```markdown
[![タージ・マハルの写真です][2]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmjId.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmjIds.jpg
```

[image: タージ・マハルの写真です]

このアルファベット 1 文字は、[Imgur の API ドキュメント](https://api.imgur.com/models/image)によると以下のものが使えます。

> ```
> 文字 名前             解像度    縦横比を保持するか
> s    Small Square     90x90     No
> b    Big Square       160x160   No
> t    Small Thumbnail  160x160   Yes
> m    Medium Thumbnail 320x320   Yes
> l    Large Thumbnail  640x640   Yes
> h    Huge Thumbnail   1024x1024 Yes
> ```

ただし以前は、いくつかの文字が機能しないバグが有りました。その当時の画像をリサイズしたい場合は、アップロードをやり直す必要が有ります。["The Stack Imgur service is no longer resizing images correctly"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314028/341401) や ["Is the continuing absence of Imgur resizing for new images still temporary, or permanent? ETA?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315004/341401) にまとめられています。